# Dynamic Metadata Assignment in an ItemGroup

Tags: msbuild, metadata, msbuild-4.0

I have an `ItemGroup` defined as:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProtoFiles Include="Protos\*.proto"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

It yields a list of all *.proto* files in a directory of my project. I want each item in the group to include a piece of metadata that specifies the name of the file that will be generated based on the *.proto* file. I know I can do this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProtoFiles Include="Protos\*.proto">
        <OutputFile>%(ProtoFiles.Filename).cs</OutputFile>
    </ProtoFiles>
</ItemGroup>
```

But my problem is that it is not a simple mapping from *.proto* filename to output filename. There is some tricky logic involved that I need to encapsulate somewhere and call that when assigning metadata. I need something like:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProtoFiles Include="Protos\*.proto">
        <OutputFile><GetOutputFilename ProtoFilename="%(ProtoFiles.Filename)"/></OutputFile>
    </ProtoFiles>
</ItemGroup>
```

The idea being that my custom `GetOutputFilename` task would be called in order to get the metadata value.

Is this possible? Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not, try instead passing the `ItemGroup` to a task to generate this metadata. [Property Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx) can operate **on** metadata values, but unfortunately [cannot be used to define metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171473.aspx#sectionToggle2).

Comment: Thanks. I looked at property functions but as far as I can tell, they do not apply in this context. That is, I cannot invoke `String.Replace` against `%(ProtoFiles.Filename)`. If you disagree, can you please update your answer with an example of how I would do this? The syntax has elluded me thus far.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know if the logic is too tricky for MSBuild without knowing exactly what it is.  Do you have a custom task that operates on @(ProtoFiles) to generate the output files?  If so, why not alter your task (or refactor to a new one) that just calculates the output files without creating them, something like this,

```
<ProtoTask
   Files="@(ProtoFiles)"
   ... other params
   DryRun="true">
   <Output
      TaskParameter="OutputFiles"
      ItemName="ProtoFiles" />
</ProtoFiles>
```

The task can clone the item array, calculate the metadata value, and assign it to the output item array, which in the example here overwrites the original item array passed into the task.